# where to find the my.ini config file for a MySQL 5.6 Windows Install

Tags: mysql, configuration

Having some memory issues - 500000 records some queries stall.

I want to increase memory for MySQL installed on windows 8. In reading - many suggest changing these values:

```
key_buffer_size         = 1G
sort_buffer_size        = 16M
tmp_table_size          = 4G
max_heap_table_size     = 8G
read_buffer_size        = 512K
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 4G
```

Amongst a few.

Can someone tell me where I find the config file - or where to place my own?,( as I do not want to change these every time I boot up.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini**

Please notice it is "**ProgramData**" NOT "Program Files".

Although, you may find a "MySQL" folder and a "my-default.ini" in "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6/"

```
(# *** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. It's a template which will be copied to the
# *** default location during install, and will be replaced if you
# *** upgrade to a newer version of MySQL.)
```

**C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini**
is the one you want to edit.